# how to Remove "open with Gitkraken" from context menu?

Tags: contextmenu, gitkraken

I have a wasteful option left after uninstalling Gitkraken in windows 7 ultimate 64bit. I have tried many options like,
in regidit i have searched in following places:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers] 
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_gui]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_shell]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_gui]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_shell]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\git_gui]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\git_shell]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell]
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\OpenWithList
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

but i have got nothing related to git or git kraken so that i can remove that option.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth noting that there are two items added to the context menu, one for each of the two right-click contexts. And as such, two entries exist in the Registry.

Context 1 - In the parent folder, when right-clicking on the folder icon of the repository:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\GitKraken`

Context 2 - Within the repository folder, right-clicking on background white-space:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\GitKraken`

I tend to use the second one more often, and there was a bug when I first installed the program. In order to fix this bug, change the last argument from `%L` to `%V`.

From:

`"C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\gitkraken\update.exe" --processStart=gitkraken.exe --process-start-args="-p %L"`

To:

`"C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\gitkraken\update.exe" --processStart=gitkraken.exe --process-start-args="-p %V"`

Answer (score 5):

The entry is here on my machine:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\GitKraken

I'm not clear from the format of your list where you were actually checking, but that might be worth a look.

Comment: Entries in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell will also remove context menus when you right click a folder

Answer (score 0):

```
[-HKEY_USERS\...
    S-1-5-21-307178686-3694073347-4169164670-1001\...
        Software\Classes\Directory\shell\GitKraken]
```

`S-1-5-21-307178686-3694073347-4169164670-1001` should be related to your user

[image: Sample]

Here is my screenshot choose the one without the classes should be right.